# WHY does it work? PHP foreach multidimensional arrays

Tags: php

I've been reading PHP for absolute beginners. The book is getting me used to some things, but it's not really explaining how and why these things work.

Can anyone recommend a book/course that will not only show me how, but why as well?

Foe example:

```
$people = array(
    'Jason' => array('gender'=> 'male', 'hair'=> 'brown'),
    'carly' => array('gender'=> 'female', 'hair'=>'blonde'),
);
foreach ($people as $name => $person){
    foreach($person as $key => $value){
        echo "$name's $key is $value. <br />";
    }
}

// Output:
// Jason's gender is male. 
// Jason's hair is brown. 
// carly's gender is female.
// carly's hair is blonde.
```

Why am I using `$key` and `$value`? What do they do? Where did `$person` come from? Could I have named that anything else I wanted to?

Comment: I've reformatted the code a bit to make it easier to see. Items on the left-hand side of `=>` are keys, things on the right are values - true at all levels of a nested array. So a value can be an array as as well as a string/number value.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick browse of the [documentation on `foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) would answer this question.

The first `foreach` is looping through all the elements of the `$people` array. Each key of the array is the `$name`, and the value (the second-level array) is the `$person`.

Then in the second loop, foreach person's attribute, the type of attribute is the `$key` and the value of that attribute is the `$value`.

Please do read that manual link I just gave, it explains it far better than me!

Answer (score 0):

As far as book/course, the best thing I have used is self-teaching and web resources. php.net has documentation for everything, and this methodology has been more than enough to get me through various professional settings. This includes, of course, things like posting on stackoverflow. I have never had the need to buy a book or take a course. These things can help, of course, but I'm not aware of any particular magic bullet solution.

In your example, PHP does not require that the variables used in a foreach loop be declared elsewhere first. The first variable in the foreach loop, `people` in your example, is the array to loop over. Then you have the keyword `as` and then the variable that will be used inside the loop for each entry in the array. If you want, you can spec that variable as `key => value` instead of just `value`.

Read the PHP documentation. Ask questions when you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The Key is the 'Jason' part, the value is the Array you're putting inside of it. Also, inside the Value array, you have a $key and $value of 'gender' and 'male' respectively.

The Foreach loop allows you to access each parent level array first, being the 'Jason', 'Carly' parts, giving you access to each value inside of those keys. In this case, you're passing another array into that, so the nested foreach loop will assign each of those values to $key => $value.

As far as reading, search Google for 'Multi-Dimensional Array Tutorial PHP' and you will find many resources to read. This is how I learned more about M-D Arrays.

Good Luck, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will look for the tutorial.

Comment: Please make sure you upvote posts that you find helpful, and be sure to mark an answer correct if you find it to be the best (correct) answer to your question so other people can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

starting from back to front:

> Could I have named that anything else I wanted to?

Yes you could have, the same as `$key` and `$value`

> Where did $person come from?

`$person` came from `$people`, explained below:

```
$people as $name => $person
```

This basically is saying take the current record of `$people` and store the key (Jason in the first record) in the variable `$name`

and store its value (`array('gender'=> 'male', 'hair'=> 'brown')` in the first row) as `$person`

> Why am I using $key and $value? What do they do?

`$key` and `$value` can be named anything as long as it's a valid variable name, and the second `foreach` loop acts the same as the first, except that instead of 'Jason' being the key, 'gender' and 'hair' are the keys, stored in `$key` and their values 'male' and 'brown' are stored in `$value` respectively

i.e. `$person` of record 1 is 'Jason', the first `$key` of `$person` ('Jason') is 'gender' and the value of that key is 'male' which is `$value`

Comment: Thank you. Light bulb. This did it!